# How to transfer a war file to a remote server using Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

How can I copy a war file using pipeline script.I have been trying this for long time and no luck on this. I have Publish Over ssh plugin installed and configured correctly. The test configuration is working fine. Following is the command which i have tried for copying war file to remote machine.

```
 sh 'scp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/heloWorld/target/heloWorld.war ubuntu@server:/home/ubuntu/jenkinsbuilds/'
```

Whenever i run i will get an error and following is the error.

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

Is there any relationship between Publish Over ssh plugin and scp command in pipeline? How can i get it working? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to the remote server authorized_keys?